# How can I query where it will only show the documents where it has a field timestamp of today's date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have these two "where" and if I'll add the "where" for the date, it's not working anymore. I just watn to show all of the orders with the order status of confirmed and a delivery date of today.

```
var start = new Date();
start.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var startOfDay = start.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(startOfDay);

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
var endOfDay = end.toUTCString();
console.log(endOfDay);

try {
  firestore
    .collection("orders")
    .where("orderStatus", "==", "Confirmed")
    .where("deliveryDate", ">=", startOfDay)
    .where("deliveryDate", "<=", endOfDay)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const orders = [];
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        orders.push({
          "Order ID": doc.id,
        });
      });
      console.log(orders);
      this.setState({ orders: orders });
      console.log(this.state.orders);
    });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

}

This is the timestamp field in firestore
[image]

[image]

Comment: How could this even work? How could you expect any document to have a date field exactly equal to the date generated on your client? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to get the same date from the one saved in the firestore and the client's date. Like same month,date, and year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I have already fixed this and this is the updated code by converting the javascript startofDay and endofday to firebase timestamp.

var start = new Date();
    start.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var startOfDay = start.toLocaleDateString();

    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    var endOfDay = end.toUTCString();
  
    var myTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
      new Date(startOfDay)
    );

    var ending = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new 
     Date(endOfDay));
    console.log("end", ending);

    try {
      firestore
        .collection("orders")
        .where("orderStatus", "==", "Confirmed")
        .where("deliveryDate", ">=", myTimestamp)
        .where("deliveryDate", "<=", ending)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the messages matching a given year, month or day you will have to

1. Store the `year`, `month` and `day` as separate fields in your document
2. Change your query (example to query for the `day`)

   ```
   firestore
   .collection("orders")
   .where("orderStatus", "==", "Confirmed")
   .where("day", "==", Math.floor(Date.now()/(1000*3600*24)))
   .get()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) contains more information. According to its docs:

> JavaScript `Date` objects represent a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. `Date` objects contain a `Number` that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

So when you call `new Date()` is represents that exact moment in time, and it is very unlikely that your database contains a document with that exact same timestamp.

That's why you'll usually want to query on a date range on [timestamp fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). So you'll determine the exact dates for the start of the day, and the end of the day, and then do:

```
firestore
    .collection("orders")
    .where("orderStatus", "==", "Confirmed")
    .where("date", ">=", startOfDay)
    .where("date", "<=", endOfDay)
```

Also see:

- [Query specific day in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539773/query-specific-day-in-firestore)
- [Cloud Firestore: Storing and querying for today's date over multiple UTC offsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533178/cloud-firestore-storing-and-querying-for-todays-date-over-multiple-utc-offsets)
- Results for searching [javascript to determine date for start and end of day](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+determine+date+for+start+and+end+of+day)

Comment: I've tried doing it like this and I'm still not getting the desired output.                                 
  `var start = new Date();'
    start.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var startOfDay = start.toUTCString();
    console.log(startOfDay);

    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    var endOfDay = end.toUTCString();
    console.log(endOfDay);

    try {
      firestore
        .collection("orders")
        .where("orderStatus", "==", "Confirmed")
        .where("deliveryDate", ">=", startOfDay)
        .where("deliveryDate", "<=", endOfDay)`

Comment: To query on a date, you have to filter on the range of timestamps. If your code doesn't work, update your question to show the new code, and show a document that you'd expect to be returned by the query.

Comment: I've edited my question already. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't convert them to strings. Just pass the `start` and `end` variables (of type `Date`) to Firestore.